# Best field of view

Tags: unity, camera, first-person-shooter, view, third-person-view

What is the best value for field of view for an FPS?

Comment: A little bit related: ["Why don't all games permit changing the field of view?"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72844/why-dont-all-games-permit-changing-the-field-of-view)

Comment: As long as i can change it,usually 90 is the sweet spot. Also consoles use completely different fovs

Comment: Now I have the field of view at 60 and I thought of decreasing it as it makes some models appear stretched

Answer (score 3):

Configurable.

The best field of view depends on many variables. For instance, how large the monitor is, are you using eyefinity, is the aspect ratio nonstandard, how far you are from the screen.

Besides that, different people have different preferences for it, leading to some people feeling simulation sickness at 90 FOV while others feel it at 75 FOV.